# Angular - Only push to array if unique

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular application that collects values of items for an invoice, I want to make sure only unique items are being added to this collection but am having no luck.

I am pushing 3 pieces of information to this collection: id, price, and type. I want to make sure there is nothing in the collection currently matching those 3 points.

```
// My container
$scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
    }]
}


    $scope.addPhoto = function() {
    console.log('Withdrawing Photo: '+ $scope.item.id);
    if ($scope.invoice.items.indexOf(item.id) != $scope.item.id)
    {
      $scope.invoice.items.push({
        id: $scope.item.id,
        price: $scope.item.price,
        type: 'photo'
    });
    }
}
```

// Trying to avoid collections like this

invoice:  { 
items: 
[  {  } ,  { 
id: 25
price: 0
type: photo
 } ,  { 
id: 25
price: 0
type: photo
 }  ]
 }

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with to solve my problem, hopefully it helps someone else.

```
    $scope.addPhoto = function () {
    console.log('Withdrawing Photo: ' + $scope.item.id);
    var newItemId = $scope.item.id;
    var newItemPrice = $scope.item.price;
    var newItemType = 'photo';
    var matches = true;


    // Make sure user hasnt already added this item
    angular.forEach($scope.invoice.items, function(item) {
        if (newItemId === item.id && newItemPrice === item.price && newItemType === item.type) {
            matches = false;
            $scope.message = 'You have already selected to withdraw this item!';
        }
    });

    // add item to collection
    if (matches != false) {
        $scope.invoice.items.push({
            id: $scope.item.id,
            price: $scope.item.price,
            type: 'photo'
        });
        $scope.total += $scope.item.price;
        $scope.message = 'Total Amount Selected';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

[`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is pretty much what you need.

```
$scope.addPhoto = function() {
    console.log('Withdrawing Photo: '+ $scope.item.id);
    var matches = $scope.invoice.items.filter(function(datum) {
      return datum.id === $scope.item.id &&
        datum.price === $scope.item.price &&
        datum.type === $scope.item.type;
    });
    if (!matches.length)
    {
      $scope.invoice.items.push({
        id: $scope.item.id,
        price: $scope.item.price,
        type: 'photo'
    });
    }
}
```

[Semi-contrived JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUhsn/)

Comment: Hmmmm it is still letting me add the same item twice (see above) for collection

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx There was a typo in my answer, see edit and JSFiddle.

Comment: Its still letting me add the same record over and over again... :/

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx My answer works for the use case you've put up (as demonstrated in the fiddle).  I don't see how I can help further.

Comment: I must be missing something because that Fiddle will not run for me, and when I use that snippet I can add the same item repeatedly

Comment: What do you mean 'the fiddle will not run'?  Are you checking the console?

Comment: I dont think     
    $scope.invoice = {
        items: [{
        }]
    }

Is the same as how you structured the container in your Fiddle.

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx How so?  It looks the same to me.  `invoice` is an object with the property `items`, which is an array containing objects.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can simple pop opposite of push

```
array.splice(array.pop(item));
```